# Html from modules being escaped

Tags: php, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, joomla-template

I have an issue with html output from a joomla module being escaped so that it's rendered as text .

I have no idea why this could happen, is it a joomla core issue?

This only started happening after an update

[image: image of visible code]

Comment: Did you updated the extension too or just the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a problem with the extension that uses the {source} tags, rather than Joomla.  Googling says this is probably Sourcerer.

Make sure that Sourcerer is also patched and that the developer says it works on the version of Joomla you have updated to.  Also check that it is still published in your plug-ins list.  Third party extensions can often stop working if you update the core code and their code is for an earlier version of Joomla (or just badly written).

Looking at the code in your example, you probably don't actually need Sourcerer to add your code anyway as it is all HTML rather than server side code - just update the editor plugin's parameters to stop it stripping the tags you want to use. NB code needs to be added in the code view rather than the WYSIWYG view of the editor.

Sourcerer is really primarily for PHP, which makes me balk as it feels like a massive hack rather than an extension designed with good practise and Joomla's framework in mind.